# Best practice: what to do when view controller is loading very long?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need an advice what to do when my view controller is loading quite long?

In my situation I have an offline map made with route-me and it takes several seconds to load the map from about 100mb database, then load a lot of markers, put them on the map, etc.
If I run this code in viewDidLoad UI seems unresponsive, because after pressing on tab or button nothing happens for a few seconds while everything is loading. If I put it in viewDidAppear map somehow doesn't get shown at all until I quit this view controller and go back to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it takes so long you should show a spinner or other "busy" indicator while you **load your data on a background thread**.

Once your time-intensive process is complete, update the UI back on the main thread and hide your spinner/busy indicator.

Executing code on a background thread is extremely easy - there are several ways to do it - but the easiest/most straight-forward way is probably with `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` as in this example:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadMap) withObject:nil];
```

When you're ready to run on the main thread again - it's the same thing, but in reverse using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(wrapupLoadMap) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Good luck.